# Fastest Way to Plot Surface Animation

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot

I have a grid of points X,Y and an array of matrices containing values of those points at different times, Z. Currently, I am outputting a surface plot image using matplotlib before appending them together to make an animation.

This is very slow since matplotlib must render each image individually meaning plotting 1000 frames of an animation take tens of minutes, code shown below

```
for i in range (len(Z)):
    axes=plt.axes(projection='3d')
    axes.plot_surface(X,Y,Z[i])
    plt.savefig(i)
```

Is there an alternative library that will allow animations to be plotted on the order of tens of seconds instead?

Comment: Did you try rasterizing the surface?  `plot_surface(x, y, Z, rasterized=True)`?

Comment: You could take a look at `pyqtgraph` or `vispy`, which is made in collaboration with the same devs, but not as easily usable yet. They are both extremely fast, because they use OpenGL to render the graphics